# Using Django class-based views, how can I return a different template if request.is_ajax

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I find Django's request.is_ajax a very useful way to add progressive enhancement via JS and still keep DRY in my views.

However, I want to use class-based views and render with a different template if request.is_ajax.

It is not clear to me how I can override my default "template_name" and make the template loading conditional in class-based views.

How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe you should add an "api" url for your class based view where the ajax call goes to with a class based view only for the ajax calls.

Comment: Sure I can do that, but that is what I want to avoid: it doesn't give me progressive enhancement, and it gives me more view and url code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The appropriate way to do this is to override the methods provided by the [`TemplateResponseMixin`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py#L105).

If you simply need to provide a different template for Ajax requests, then override `get_template_names`. If you want to provide a different response altogether, say a `application/json` response, then override `render_to_response` to produce a different `HttpResponse` for Ajax requests.

Comment: thanks, this answers my question, and goes further to point me in the right direction for overriding not just the template but the response object.

Answer (score 11):

Override [get_template_names](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin.get_template_names):

```
def get_template_names(self):
    if self.request.is_ajax():
        return ['ajax_template.html']
    else:
        return ['standard_template.html']
```