# Django Templating: Render CreateView one-time with base.html and base_popup.html

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a class-based view `FooCreate` and I want to use it on two different pages:

- normal create view: With all the normal header and footer parts: Extending my base.html
- in popup: Here I want no visible header and footer part: Extending (the not existing yet) base_popup.html

I would like to implement this without a single "if", since I like condition-less code :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Django class-based views, how can I return a different template if request.is\_ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782025/using-django-class-based-views-how-can-i-return-a-different-template-if-request)

Comment: Perhaps it could help if you explain why you don't like conditions. Conditions are everywhere, even if you don't use an `if` statement explicitely.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to checkout [how Django Admin handles this with `IS_POPUP_VAR`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py).

Basically, Django Admin uses a '_popup' parameter passed in the querystring. You can then pass a "base_layout" variable to context.

```
class MyView(View):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        if '_popup' in request.GET:
            kwargs['base_layout'] = 'base_popup.html'
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

And your templates would start with:

```
{% extends base_layout|default:"base.html" %}
```